# How to add items to a listbox via GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox, uicontrol

I am desperately trying to create a logbox for my GUI.
What i would like to do is for the start, to write text in a list after having pushed a PUSH Button. 
The Callback function of the PUSH Button is:

```
function run__Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

   initial_name=cellstr(get(handles.logbox1,'String'))
    handles.names={'test','haus', 'top', 'down', 'optimistic'}
    handles.names{end,end}=[]                                   %Add Element for new text 
    handles.names{end,end}='neuuu'                              %Add Element
    num_element=length(handles.names)                           %Count Elements
    set(handles.logbox1,'String',handles.names)                 %Aktualisiere Liste

    set(handles.logbox1,'Top',num_element)                      %Set Listbox to the last Element
```

and the listbox is in the same GUI. Nevertheless, there is the error:

rror using hg.uicontrol/set

```
The name 'Top' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'uicontrol'.
```

Can anyone help me please, i dont understand whats wrong?

Best regards, John

Comment: I don't understand. You wish to add new elements in the listbox each time the pushbutton is pressed?

Comment: logbox1 ist the tag to the listbox, sorry for this confusion. Its named like that becaue it shall log all the steps done in the GUI. Every time i push a button in the GUI or its SUBGUIs i would like to see the action in the logbox.....so add the item with a textstring to the logbox and make the focus of the logbox on the last element! but i get this error when i try to set the focus correctly and i dont know how to access the logbox from other Callbacks and set its value...would be glad for your help! best regards, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the error because `Top` is not a `property` of the `listbox uicontrol`; moreover, `Top` is not a property of any `uicontrol`.

You can find [here the list of uicontrol properties.](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html)

The most listbox property close to "Top" is `ListboxTop`.

I've created two simple GUIs that could help you managing the acccess to the listbox.

The Main GUI "add_to_listbox" contains:

- a `listbox` with `tag` listbox1
- a `pushbutton` with `tag` pushbutton1, `String` "Add Action": each time the user pushes it, a string such as "Main GUI: Inserted string #x" is added on top of listbox ("x" is a conter)
- a `pushbutton` with `tag` "open_subgui", `String` "Open SubGUI" to open the second GUI

The SubGUI ("add_to_listbox_subgui") contains

- a `pushbutton` with `tag` pushbutton1, `String` "Add Action on Main GUI": each time the user pushes it, a string such as "SUB GUI Inserted string #x" is added on top of the Main GUI listbox ("x" is a conter)

The SubGUI handles the addition of strings to the Main GUI listbox by using the Main GUi `listbox handle` which is stored in the Main GUI `guidata` (when the SubGUI is opened by the Main GUI, it receives as input the `handle` to the Main GUI; through it the SubGUI access to the Main GUI `guidata`).

In the following you can find the:

- Main GUI `OpeningFcn` in which the "action counter" in initialized
- Main GUI `pushbutton1_Callback` that adds a string in the listbox each time the `pushbutton` is pressed
- Main GUI `open_subgui_Callback` which opens the SubGUI
- SubGUI `OpeningFcn` in which both SubGUI and Main GUI `guidata` are handled
- SubGUI `pushbutton1_Callback` that adds a string in the Main GUI listbox each time the `pushbutton` is pressed

**Main GUI `OpeningFcn`**

```
% --- Executes just before add_to_listbox is made visible.
function add_to_listbox_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to add_to_listbox (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for add_to_listbox
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes add_to_listbox wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Get Main GUI guidata
gui_data=guidata(gcf);
% Add (and initialize) button action counter to Main GUI guidata
gui_data.btn_action=0;
% Set Main GUI guidata
guidata(gcf,gui_data);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
```

**Main GUI `pushbutton1_Callback`**

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Add button action (from Main GUI) string to the listbox
%
% Get Mani GUI guidata
gui_data=guidata(gcf);
% Increment button action counter
gui_data.btn_action=gui_data.btn_action+1;
% Set Main GUI guidata (to store button action counter)
guidata(gcf,gui_data);
% Generate action string and add it to the listbox
% The firt strimg is directly add to the listbox
if(gui_data.btn_action == 1)
   new_str='Main GUI: Inserted string #1';
   set(handles.listbox1,'string',new_str);
else
   new_str=['Main GUI: Inserted string #' num2str(gui_data.btn_action)];
   % The fisrt string in the list box is returned as "string", to add the
   % second one, it has has to be first converted into a cellarray
   if(gui_data.btn_action == 2)
      tmp_str=cellstr(get(handles.listbox1,'string'));
   else
      % The order of the string in the listbox is reversed to have the last
      % one on top
      tmp_str=flipud(get(handles.listbox1,'string'));
   end
   % Set the updated set of seting to the listbox
   tmp_str{end+1,1}=new_str;
   set(handles.listbox1,'string',flipud(tmp_str));
end
```

**Main GUI `open_subgui_Callback`**

```
% --- Executes on button press in open_subgui.
function open_subgui_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open_subgui (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Open the Sub GUI; the handle of the Main GUI is passed as argument to
% This allows Sub GUI accessing to the Main GUI guidata
add_to_listbox_subgui(gcf)
% Disable the "Open Sub GUI" button
set(handles.open_subgui,'enable','off')
```

**SubGUI `OpeningFcn`**

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Add Sub GUI button action string to Main GUI listbox
%
% Get Sub GUI guidata
gui_data=guidata(gcf);
% Get Main GUI guidata, "gui_data.main_gui" holds the Main GUI handle
gui_data.main_gui_data=guidata(gui_data.main_gui);
% Increment the button action counter
gui_data.btn_action=gui_data.main_gui_data.btn_action+1;
% Update Main GUI button actin counter
main_gui_data=guidata(gui_data.main_gui);
main_gui_data.btn_action=gui_data.btn_action;
% Store Sub GUI guidata
guidata(gcf,gui_data);
% Store Main GUI guidata
guidata(gui_data.main_gui,main_gui_data);
%
% Add button action (from Main GUI) string to the listbox
%
if(gui_data.btn_action == 1)
   % Generate action string and add it to the Main GUI listbox
   % The firt strimg is directly add to the listbox
   new_str='SUB GUI Inserted string #1';
   set(gui_data.listbox,'string',new_str);
else
   new_str=['SUB GUI Inserted string #' num2str(gui_data.btn_action)];
   % The fisrt string in the list box is returned as "string", to add the
   % second one, it has has to be first converted into a cellarray
   if(gui_data.btn_action == 2)
      tmp_str=cellstr(get(gui_data.listbox,'string'));
   else
      % The order of the string in the listbox is reversed to have the last
      % one on top
      tmp_str=flipud(get(gui_data.listbox,'string'));
   end
   % Set the updated set of seting to the listbox
   tmp_str{end+1,1}=new_str;
   set(gui_data.listbox,'string',flipud(tmp_str));
end
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy I've been of use to you. Perhaps You might want to accept the answer to close the questione :-)